# Trying to understand how [::-1] works in Python

Tags: python

What does `g(xs[:-2])` mean?

```py
def f(xs):
    def g(ys):
        return ys[::-1]
    
    return [x-2+(2*7/4) for x in g(xs[:-2])]
```

Comment: It passes `xs` without last 2 elements to `g()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it works, it passes `xs` variable (a string/list) and slices it to remove the last two elements/characters (-2 means to slice from the end of string/list) to function `g()`